# Cannot access samba server in "parent" subnet

Tags: windows-10, networking, samba

I have been searching for a solution to my problem for the past 2 days and I just cannot find anything related :(

My network setup is the following:
[image]

Now my goal is to be able to access the fileserver from PC-1(win10) and PC-2(win10) at the same time.
I can access the web-interface of my fileserver(running TrueNAS) from both computers.
However when I try to connect via smb from PC-2 I get an unspecified error. I ran the Windows troubleshooter which returned something along the lines of "the server is online but not responding to connection attempts".

Things I have tested/tried:

- When I use PC-2 in the 181 subnet it works without any issues
- I tried disabling the firewall on PC-2, seems not be the issue
- I hosted a smb fileserver on the 181 router which also was inaccessible
- I tried playing with the subnetmask however that did not help, not sure I did it right though

Any help wpuld be very much appreciated!
Kind regards :)

## Solved

Turns out the 180 router was blocking the samba traffic. Now after changing the firewall settings it is working!

Comment: Have you tried installing network monitoring software (e.g. Wireshark) so that you could _see_ where the packets go? Also, your diagram doesn't actually say what subnet mask each interface has, so there's no way to tell if those are right or not. (The diagram should also include addresses for _all_ interfaces of a router -- it generally doesn't make sense for a router to have just one address like that.)

Comment: @Daniel - please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.